# errors in xeCJK.sty ? on last xelatex from Miktex

Tags: xetex, xecjk, miktex2.9

```
% Compile with xelatex
% UTF-8 encoding
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\begin{document}
文章内容
\end{document}
```

gives xx errors (xeCJK.sty line 637 ) when xelatex'ed under Miktex-2.9.6520-x64
.log file

```
**./testNewXECJK5.tex
(testNewXECJK5.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(...)
Package: xeCJK 2017/11/22 v3.5.1 Typesetting CJK scripts with XeLaTeX

(C:\Users\atl\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xtemplate\xtemp
late.sty
Package: xtemplate 2017/12/16 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
\l__xtemplate_tmp_dim=\dimen134
\l__xtemplate_tmp_int=\count166
\l__xtemplate_tmp_muskip=\muskip16
\l__xtemplate_tmp_skip=\skip49
) (xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2012/07/16 v3990 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count167
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count168
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count169
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count170
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count171
)
(C:\Users\atl\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys
2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2017/12/16 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
\l__xeCJK_tmp_int=\count172
\l__xeCJK_tmp_box=\box42
\l__xeCJK_tmp_dim=\dimen135
\l__xeCJK_tmp_skip=\skip50
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \xeCJKShipoutHook with arg. spec. '' on line 148.
.................................................
\g__xeCJK_spacefactor_int=\count173
\l__xeCJK_begin_int=\count174
\l__xeCJK_end_int=\count175
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "kernel/invalid-variant"
* 
* Variant form 'c' invalid for base form '\__xeCJK_CJK_class_tl:n'.
*************************************************
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. Defining document command \makexeCJKactive with arg. spec. '' on line 379.
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. Defining document command \makexeCJKinactive with arg. spec. '' on line 380.
\c__xeCJK_CJK_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass1
\c__xeCJK_FullLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass2
\c__xeCJK_FullRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass3
\c__xeCJK_HalfLeft_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass4
\c__xeCJK_HalfRight_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass5
\c__xeCJK_NormalSpace_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass6
\c__xeCJK_CM_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass7
\c__xeCJK_HangulJamo_class_int=\XeTeXcharclass8
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \xeCJKDeclareCharClass with arg. spec.
. 's>{\TrimSpaces }mm' on line 545.
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \__xeCJK_set_char_class_aux:Nnw with arg. spec.
. 'm>{\SplitArgument {1}{->}}m' on line 566.
.................................................
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "kernel/invalid-variant" 
* Variant form 'nc' invalid for base form '\xeCJK_declare_char_class:nn'.
*************************************************
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \normalspacedchars with arg. spec. 'm' on line 613.
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. Defining document command \xeCJKResetPunctClass with arg. spec. '' on line624.
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command" 
. Defining document command \xeCJKResetCharClass with arg. spec. '' on line
. 636.
.................................................
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__bool_>_0: 
l.637 \xeCJKResetCharClass

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__bool_\__bool_>_0:_0: 
l.637 \xeCJKResetCharClass

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

+++ several times the same line 637++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
SimSun font is installed (Windows)
Thanks for any comments

Comment: You have an very outdated xparse.sty in your document folder `(xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2012/07/16 v3990`. Delete it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You have an very outdated xparse.sty in your document folder

```
 (xparse.sty Package: xparse 2012/07/16 v3990.
```

Delete it and try again.